# How do I save form data in .yml file on submit using vue js?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I am working on a resume generator and I want to be able to save the 
input form data into a .yml file but I can't seem to find any article 
to give me some clues. I want that once the submit button is clicked, the data is automatically written in the .yml file

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<template>
    <div class="biography">
        <h2>Fill in your education information</h2>
        <label for="degree">Degree</label>
        <input id="degree"  type="text">
        <br/>
        <label for="from">From</label>
        <input id="from" type="date">
        <br/>
        <label for="to">To</label>
        <input id="to"  type="date">
        <br/>
        <button id="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
</template>
```

```js
<script>
    export default {
        name: "Education"
    }
</script>
```

```css
<style scoped>
    input {
        margin-left: 100px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        border: 2px;
        width: 300px;
        height: 3em;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    button {
        font-size: 16px;
        padding: 10px;
        background-color: #004d4d;
        color: white;
        border-radius: 6px;
    }
    button:active {
        background-color: #00e6e6;
    }
    label {
        position: absolute;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you write a function that will turn the input values into a string that represents valid YAML text, you can use the Blob API to turn it into a file.

As media type, use the same type as the other YAML files your company uses ( text/yaml, application/yaml, text/vnd.yaml, etc ) since we ( afaik ) do not have a standard type yet for YAML files.

To actually save the file, you'll need to create a url from that Blob the user can click to download. ( See the multitude of other questions about that here on SO or any JS blob-to-url tutorial. )

If you are actually submitting a form to a serverside script, there's probably a bunch of server libraries that can create a YAML file you can return as the response to a form POST request.